# Perl scripts suddenly compiling very slowly

Tags: perl

Suddenly, compiling my perl scripts started taking too much time. (About a minute each)

It doesn't really matter what I have in the scripts, what does matter, however, is how many `require` and `use` I use.

I think it is in compiling, but I am not sure. The thing is - if I run only the checking part - meaning, `perl -c script.h`, it takes about the same time.

My question is - how to debug it, how to find out, what exactly is perl doing, to find out what takes so much time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check how long each use an require command takes to load with something like the following (time is a unix/linux command, so on Windows you'll need to keep an eye on your watch):

```
$ time perl -c -e 'use strict;'
-e syntax OK

real    0m0.122s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Just change the use/require line for each entry you have to find which one results in the longest time.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the "bottleneck" is Moose, that takes 10 seconds for every script it's in. It is weird, because it didn't do that just yesterday.....

Comment: OK, problem solved, it was a problem on the server with somehow broken filesystem. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to have helped.  Guess this means it's time to take another backup in case the problem is with the harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) utility to see disk I/O activity. If you have suspicion on Moose, running isolated script could show what is loaded and when.